# Invalid property 'username' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'username' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I'm getting following error while running my Spring MVC web application:-

**org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'username' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'username' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?**

Why error is pointing to a String class like java.lang.String? It should take from my UserForm object.

UserForm:-

```
package myspring;

/**
 * @author vinod827
 *
 */
public class UserForm {


    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Controller Class (LoginPageController):-

```
/**
 * 
 */
package myspring;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * @author vinod827
 *
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginPageController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginPageController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage(ModelMap modelMap){
        logger.info("**************");
        UserForm userForm = new UserForm();
        modelMap.addAttribute("userForm", "userForm");
        return "login";
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String verifyLogin(UserForm userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap modelMap){
        logger.info("********&&&&&&&&&******");
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";       
        logger.info(username+":"+password);
        userForm = (UserForm) modelMap.get(userForm);       
        modelMap.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);
        return "success";
    }
}
```

JSP:-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sign-In</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Secure Sign-in</h3>
<form:form method="post" action="login" commandName="userForm">
   <form:input path="username" type="text"/>
   <form:errors path="username" /><br>
   <form:input path="password" type="password"/>
   <form:errors path="password" /><br><br>
    <form:button  id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</form:button> 
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please advise on this where I'm making the mistake?
I tried refactor the class name of UserForm to just 'User.java' and also rename username to user accordingly on JSP as well but still showing same error.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

In LoginPageController, change to

```
modelMap.addAttribute("userForm", new UserForm());
```